# HighCharts - Renderer function not working in export URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, callback, export

I am using export URL to get the rendered chart as an image.Everything is working fine. But the renderer method is not working in the export method.

But while rendering as a normal chart its working.After some research I came to know that we could use callback. But no hope. No idea about that.

If you check in the fiddle, the above chart is the normal chart and the   below one is the image where I used the export URL to save it as an image. Finally the exported URL I am getting in text box.

I am using both circle and text rendering method. Please help me where I am getting wrong.

```
$(function () {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'DNA Slim Burn Concept'
    },
     legend: {
        enabled: true
    },

    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Duration (Weeks)'
        },
        categories: ['1', '20', '30']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Weight (Kg)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },

     series: [{

         color: '#000',
         lineWidth: 2,
        data: [{ marker: {
                fillColor: '#EE9A4D',
                symbol: 'triangle',
                lineWidth: 3,
                lineColor: "#EE9A4D" 
        },y:65}, { marker: {
                fillColor: '#3BB9FF',
                symbol: 'circle',
                lineWidth: 3,
                lineColor: "#3BB9FF" 
        },y:55}, { marker: {
                fillColor: '#59E817',
                symbol: 'square',
                lineWidth: 3,
                lineColor: "#59E817" 
        },y:50}]        
    }],

},

function(chart) { // on complete

    //Render Circle
     chart.renderer.circle(100, 235, 5).attr({
        fill: '#3BB9FF',
     }).add();

    // Render the text 
    chart.renderer.text('<span style="color: #3BB9FF">Data 1</span>', 110, 240).css({
        color: '#4572A7',
        fontSize: '12px',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }).attr({
        // why doesn't zIndex get the text in front of the chart?
        zIndex: 999
    }).add();

    // Render the Square
    chart.renderer.rect(95, 245, 10, 10, 0)
        .attr({
            fill: '#59E817',
        }).add();

    // Render the text  for square
    chart.renderer.text('<span style="color: #59E817">Data 2</span>', 110, 255).css({
        color: '#59E817',
        fontSize: '12px',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }).attr({
        zIndex: 999
    }).add();
 });



  var options = {
     chart: {
        type: 'line',
        renderTo: 'chart',
         events:{
                        load:function(){
                            //Render Circle
     chart.renderer.circle(100, 235, 5).attr({
        fill: '#3BB9FF',
     }).add();

    // Render the text 
    chart.renderer.text('<span style="color: #3BB9FF">Data 1</span>', 110, 240).css({
        color: '#4572A7',
        fontSize: '12px',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }).attr({
        // why doesn't zIndex get the text in front of the chart?
        zIndex: 999
    }).add();

    // Render the Square
    chart.renderer.rect(95, 245, 10, 10, 0)
        .attr({
            fill: '#59E817',
        }).add();

    // Render the text  for square
    chart.renderer.text('<span style="color: #59E817">Data 2</span>', 110, 255).css({
        color: '#59E817',
        fontSize: '12px',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }).attr({
        zIndex: 999
    }).add();
         }
      }
  },

    title: {
        text: 'Concept'
    },
     legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Duration (Weeks)'
        },
        categories: ['1', '20', '30']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Weight (Kg)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },

     series: [{
         color: '#000',
         lineWidth: 2,
         data: [{ marker: {
                fillColor: '#EE9A4D',
                //symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)',
                symbol: 'triangle',
                lineWidth: 3,
                lineColor: "#EE9A4D" // inherit from series
        },y:65}, { marker: {
                fillColor: '#3BB9FF',
                symbol: 'circle',
                lineWidth: 3,
                lineColor: "#3BB9FF" // inherit from series
        },y:55}, { marker: {
                fillColor: '#59E817',
                symbol: 'square',
                lineWidth: 3,
                lineColor: "#59E817" // inherit from series
        },y:50}]        
    }]  ,


    exporting: {
        sourceWidth: 400,
        sourceHeight: 300,

    }

 }; 

// URL to Highcharts export server
var exportUrl = 'http://export.highcharts.com/';
// POST parameter for Highcharts export server
var object = {
  options: JSON.stringify(options),
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  async: true
};

// Ajax request
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: exportUrl,
data: object,
   success: function (data) {       
    // Update "src" attribute with received image URL
    $('#chart').attr('src', exportUrl + data);
    var chart_vv = exportUrl + data;
    $('#chart-value').val(chart_vv);
   }
 });    
});
```

This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/413wp2hk/6/)

Comment: :) It worked. Hope this help someone. I have managed to solve the problem myself.
Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afytLb8v/3/

Comment: For using this data in PHP you can post the input field as $_POST['chart-value'] and save the URL to DB or so...This would be really helpful when you want the chart to be shown in PDF.